# I wouldn’t have any more to drink, if I were you

Tags: pronouns, to-infinitive

> I wouldn’t have any more to drink, if I were you.

Does the sentence look idiomatic, sound idiomatic, or look or sound grammatical?

'more' in "any more" could be an object "as a pronoun" of the verb 'have, which could mean *drink or own'*'? If so is the case, 'to drink' modifies its object, "more" as a "pronoun" ?

edit: the question is "parts of speech of "more" in the sentence above

Comment: The sentence is fine but I don't understand anything in your last paragraph.

Comment: parts of speech of the "more"

Comment: Of course _have_ doesn't mean _own_ here! The sense is "I wouldn't drink any more", and _more_ is a pronoun.

Comment: @KateBunting It's actually a determinative here. We understand "I wouldn’t have any _more alcohol_ to drink". "More" can also be an adverb, as in "It's more expensive than I expected". But, despite what some dictionaries tell us, it's never a pronoun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical and idiomatic. what we have in your sentence is most easily described as an example of ellipsis.

English like most, probably all, languages exhibits ellipsis, the omission of a word or phrase in certain situations if what is omitted is obvious from context.

The most common ellipsis in English is the omission of “that” to front a restrictive clause.

Here the word omitted is “alcohol,” a noun for which “more” is an adjective.

**EDIT**: I would hate to disagree with Kate Bunting, whose comments are always worthwhile. I am sure that you can analyze this sentence by saying that “more” is an adjective of a type that can act as a pronoun. I merely note that then there is no referent for the pronoun so again we have ellipsis of a noun. Because ellipsis is necessary to either her analysis or mine, I see no need to disagree with her.

Comment: What do you mean by "to front a restrictive clause"? What's the meaning of 'front'?

Comment: “I saw the car the murderer fled in” has a restrictive relative clause. Such clauses in sentences of greater complexity must be preceded or “fronted” by the relative pronouns “who,”, “whom,” “which,” or “that.” My example shows ellipsis of a relative pronoun. “I saw the car thar the murderer fled in.”

Comment: Oxford gives: (Pronoun) - a greater or additional amount of something. I agree that 'more of what?' is left unstated.